Qt::FindDirectChildren does not work, but should
I'm having some trouble with the Qt Object tree. I have a RangeValidator that inherits from a ValidatorInterface. I create it on the heap and couple the parent to it for memory management. This parent is the SettingsForm.
However, even though the new RangeValidator is coupled to the form directly (using "this"), it does not seem to find it as a direct child. It only finds it recursively. You can see this in the debugger's "Locals" tab.
Note that the RangeValidator-object is a direct child of the SettingsForm. I've checked in the debugger under QObject::children.
Anyone have a clue whats going on here? I can't seem to figure this out.

EDIT:
It looks like it has something to do with the QString& name parameter. When changing it to an empty string (aka match all) it does find it directly AND recursively as well. The previous recursive finds were actually bogus. I'm missing how the setObjectName() fails to be used like I would expect.
//finds the child
BalVfpValidatorInterface* childDirect = this->findChild<BalVfpValidatorInterface*>(QString(), Qt::FindDirectChildrenOnly);
//does not find the child
BalVfpValidatorInterface* childDirect2 = this->findChild<BalVfpValidatorInterface*>(QString("customValidator"), Qt::FindDirectChildrenOnly);

Code:
SettingsForm.cpp
SettingsForm::SettingsForm(QWidget* pParent, const QString& name)
    : DialogForm(staticMetaObject.className(), pParent, name)
{
    setupUi(this);
}


SettingsForm::~SettingsForm (void)
{
}
void SettingsForm::formInitialized(void)
{

    RangeValidator rangeValidator = new RangeValidator(this);
    rangeValidator.setObjectName("customValidator");

    ValidatorInterface* childRecursive = this->findChild<ValidatorInterface*>("customValidator", Qt::FindChildrenRecursively);
    ValidatorInterface* childDirect = this->findChild<ValidatorInterface*>("customValidator", Qt::FindDirectChildrenOnly);

    QList<ValidatorInterface*> childrenRecursive = this->findChildren<ValidatorInterface*>("customValidator", Qt::FindChildrenRecursively);
    QList<ValidatorInterface*> childrenDirect = this->findChildren<ValidatorInterface*>("customValidator", Qt::FindDirectChildrenOnly);

    
    DialogForm::formInitialized();
}

ValidatorInterface.h
class CORE_EXPORT ValidatorInterface : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ValidatorInterface(QObject* pParent) : QObject(pParent){};
    virtual ~ValidatorInterface() {};

public:
    /*!
     * @brief This function will give a default implementation for parameter support.
     * @details This function should be overridden if the validator needs dynamic properties from the parameter.
     * @param value The value to validate
     * @param pParameter The parameter to use dynamics from
     * @return If value is valid.
     */
    virtual bool validate(const QVariant& value, Parameter* pParameter) {
        return validate(value);
    }
    /*!
     * @brief Validates a value
     * @param value The value to validate
     * @return If it is valid.
     */
    virtual bool validate(const QVariant& value) = 0;

};

RangeValidator.cpp
#include "rangevalidator.h"
#include "validatorinterface.h"

RangeValidator::RangeValidator(QObject* pParent)
    : ValidatorInterface(pParent)
{
}


RangeValidator::~RangeValidator()
{
}

bool RangeValidator::validate(const QVariant& value) 
{
    if (!value.canConvert<double>())
    {
        return false;
    }

    double l_val = value.toDouble();

    return (l_val <= m_max) && (l_val >= m_min);
}


This is the same as your previous question (now deleted) with some minor change regarding the use of the name parameter in the search.  If I write some simple test code it all works exactly as expected (Linux + Qt5.15.8).

this is because it got downvoted to oblivion and got closed, not helping my situation, even though I edited the question as you asked. Not saying this is you, but this is the reason I posted the question again.

@AmparoWalter Closure isn't definitive, just like votes. Besides, you deleted your post less than 10 minutes after editing it, so you didn't give enough chances to its review and reopening votes. You need to leave enough time for those processes, just like you should always take proper time to write a proper question to begin with.

@musicamante You know all to well that downvoted questions get less coverage. This post just proves that. In any case, Ill do better next time.

@AmparoWalter That's one more reason for ensuring that a question is complete, including all necessary details and sufficient code, when posting it. That post also got some level of interaction, meaning that it's likely that the downvotes would've been reverted (possibly changed to upvotes instead): I for one was going to change my vote after seeing that it was updated as requested, and it's quite possible that others would've done the same, given enough time (certainly more than a few minutes). Yet, your deletion prevented it.

@musicamante Thanks for your effords! Like I said, Ill try better next time :-)

I've managed to find it. This is a stupid mistake. QT is perfectly fine. I set the ObjectName at line 30, however. This is regarding the object on the stack. They are different objects. Using the pointer and pointer operator (->), I actually call the right object. The one that is tied to the form. Now that object has an actual name (default this is an empty string), and can be found using the QString& name parameter.
RangeValidator rangeValidator = new RangeValidator(this);
rangeValidator.setObjectName("customValidator");

Should become:
RangeValidator* rangeValidator = new RangeValidator(this);
rangeValidator->setObjectName("customValidator");


Your IDE should highlight the first version as an error.

@iknownothing Clearly it didnt, and it compiled correctly. It probably just copied the object on the stack.

Note that you can, to some extent, mitigate against bugs like this by declaring your RangeValidator(QObject* pParent) as explicit.
